# Inserting multiple QCheckBox into QTableWidget odd rows

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

I'm trying to create a table with 160 Rows, and then inserting a `QCheckBox` every odd number of rows, specifically on column 10. The problem is, i have to create 80 `QCheckBox` (one for each row, so they can be separately assigned by the user)...

Creating one by one the 80 `QCheckBox` objects for the 9 projects I have to do is simply nonsense!

Is there any way of doing that by a loop? I can't think of anything,  I searched for the answer and found nothing.

```
[...]
# importing PySide
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore
[...]
# Creating a Table
class Table(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Table, self).__init__(parent)
        self.table = QtGui.QTableWidget()
        self.table.setRowCount(160)
        self.table.setColumnCount(10)
# This is the tricky part:
        chkBoxItem = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
        chkBoxItem.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable|QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
        chkBoxItem.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)

        chkBoxItem2 = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
        chkBoxItem2.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable|QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
        chkBoxItem2.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)

        chkBoxItem3 = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
        chkBoxItem3.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable|QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
        chkBoxItem3.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
[...]
# Then insert all of them in the Table:
        self.table.setItem(0, 10, chkBoxItem)
        self.table.setItem(2, 10, chkBoxItem2)
        self.table.setItem(4, 10, chkBoxItem3)
        self.table.setItem(6, 10, chkBoxItem4)
        self.table.setItem(8, 10, chkBoxItem5)
        self.table.setItem(10, 10, chkBoxItem6)
        self.table.setItem(12, 10, chkBoxItem7)
[...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This basic script creates an UI containing a 160*10 QTable and a QPushButton.
Every odd row, a checkbox is added in the cell of the 10th column.
Clicking on the button displays a list of the state of all checkboxes.

**States**:

- 0: Unchecked
- 2: Checked
- There is a state 1 but I don't remember what
  it is used for, I'll check the docs.

**Note:**

This has been made using PyQt

**Code:**

```
import math, sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import Qt, QTimer
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)

        #Create Basic UI
        self.mainWidget = QWidget(self)
        self.table = QTableWidget()
        self.table.setRowCount(160)
        self.table.setColumnCount(10)

        self.button = QPushButton("Print stuff")

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self.mainWidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.table)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.mainWidget)

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.printStuff)
        #################

        #Fill the table 
        self.rowRange = range(0, self.table.rowCount(), 2)
        for i in self.rowRange:
            chkBoxItem = QTableWidgetItem()
            chkBoxItem.setFlags(Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable|Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
            chkBoxItem.setCheckState(Qt.Unchecked)
            self.table.setItem(i, 9, chkBoxItem)
        ###############

    def printStuff(self): #You can remove this, this is for testing purpose only
        print [(i+1, self.table.item(i, 9).checkState()) for i in self.rowRange]

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I have something urgent to do right now, so my answer isn't very elaborated. I'll get back to you later if I can have some time. Your question needs a little bit of edition too, I'll tell you what is wrong in it (nothing important).

Comment: I've changed your original post, you can see the edits here: [Edits made](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30531228/revisions)
I corrected some formulation, removed the "Run snippet" which is mainly for js scripts. No need to apologies in your post for your bad english, most of the people here are not native speakers. As long as you are understandable, it's ok. No need to say thank you either or that any help is appreciated, helping people on SO should be a pleasure (and is in my case). People from SO are happy to help people and receive help when needed. Welcome on SO btw.

Comment: I tried to add stateChanged event but there is an error when I run "AttributeError: 'QTableWidgetItem' object has no attribute 'stateChanged'"

Comment: I can't really help you without seeing your code. As stated in the error, `QTableWidgetItem` does not have a `stateChanged` signal. You are not using a real `QCheckBox` here. If you want to use `QCheckBox` signals, you need to subclass your `QTableWidgetItem` into a `QCheckBox`. If you don't know how to do so, create a new question, describe what you are trying to achieve and post your code. Then, post a link to your question here, i'll be glad to help you.